# Input Latency not updated for Browse-To-Watch

Tags: cobalt

Herewith we are currently using the Cobalt-11.153049 for YouTube application and input latency is not updated for the Browse-to-Watch application URL due to keydown start time stat which is smaller than animation start time stat and also animations has started before the key event has been dispatched. So input Latency is updated as N/A in our device & **PC Based Ubuntu 16.04**(Gold & QA build) also. So please advise us to narrow-down this issue.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out to us. We're working on that problem and will keep you posted.

Comment: By the way, the parameter you mentioned was shared under NDA, and not supposed to be posted in the public space. Can you please remove that parameter in your post?

Comment: Yes Mr.Daniel Juyung Seo. We have removed the parameter in our post.

Comment: Hi @sstechsupport-eng, I can still see the parameter in your post above. Can you please remove the url again? I was referring to the parameter in the url.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. We have removed that URL parameter also in our post.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will let you know once this issue is solved. By the way, how urgent is this?